# Angular forEach to get both JSON key name and value?

Tags: angularjs, json

How can I get both the key name and value of a JSON object using Angular's `forEach` method?

```
   var institute = {
      "courses": [],
      "user_type": 3,
      "institute_name": "sd",
      "tagline": "sd",
      "overview": "sd",
      "specialities": "sd",
      "image": "dsd(2).sql"
    };
```

The above is the JSON data I've in a variable `institute` I need to access both the name and value. I've tried this:

```
angular.forEach(data,function (key,value){
     //key returns 0,1,2,3
     //value returns courses,user_type etc 
     //i need like eg) fd.append(user_type,3);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your loop args to:

`angular.forEach(data,function (value, key)`

and then:

`fd.append(key, value);`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L8Lyj15o/)

[Documetation for angular.forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach)

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is `angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) { ... })`.

Check out the fiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/21318/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get all the names in your object, then loop over those:

```
angular.forEach(Object.keys(data), function(key) {
    fd.append(key, data[key]);
});
```